# How to disable (or escape) interpolation in a DOM attribute?

Tags: angularjs

I need to show the curly brace notation to the user, as input value. Also the user should be able to type curly braces to the input. I need to get the value **with the** curly braces.

I can't use `ng-non-bindable` expression because I need to get the value from the input. I tried something like this but I got a lexer error:

```
<input value="{{ '{{ first_name }}' }}">
```

I want to put `{{ first_name }}` as the default input value.

Comment: `<input ng-model="person.firstName" />`, and set the model.firstName to the value you want. The model is the single point of truth.

Comment: @JBNizet What if I want to use it in `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: `<input placeholder="{{ model.placeholder }}" /> `, and set the model.placeholder to the value you want.

Comment: Yes this can help me. Can you add this as an answer please? So I can accept it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use binding with the model, and place whatever value you want in the model. For example:

```
<input ng-model="person.firstName" />
```

where `model.firstName` is the value you want.

Or

```
<input placeholder="{{ model.placeholder }}" />
```